# Retaining first value across multiple rows

Tags: sas

[image]

Hello,

Simple question. How do I keep the first score (AVALXC) once in the first row and the rest of the crows column blank per PATID?. so PATID 10017 would have a score of 12 for row 1 but wouldn't repeat and then the same for 100022 etc.This is what I tried.

```
proc sql;
    create table distinctSSI as
        select distinct SUBJID
                        ,AVALXC
                        
        from adtte
        where AVALXC is not null
    order by 1;
quit;
proc sort data=adtte; by SUBJID;
data FINALa;
    merge adtte (drop=AVALXC)
          distinctSSI;
    by SUBJID;
    RUN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not first.patid then call missing(avalxc);
```

Comment: @datat_null_ No i tried that and different variations of retain, first. last. it but no luck

Comment: do you have BY PATID;

Comment: proc sort data=adtte out=final;
    by patid;
run;

data finala;
set final;
by patid;
if not first.patid then call missing(avalxc);
run;